# Trigger flash events using the default browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, flash, scrollbars

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to achieve the following.

Using the default browser scrollbars, I would like to either control a timeline in flash or send _global variables into flash. I also need to detect if the scrollbar is going up or down.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to expose an [external interface](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html) to JavaScript. Then you can use the [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll) method to communicate the scroll events.

Comment: Do you know if using window.onscroll can also detect scroll direction and even perhaps scroll velocity?

Comment: You can use window.pageYOffset to get the current Y position, you can compare this to the last value to get the direction or vector for velocity. It might be better to do this using a timer instead of the scroll event.